# Getting wifi name and other details of wifi in windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

I want to get all details of wifi such as its name and other details in a windows phone app using c# language.

Please suggest me some way to do this.

Comment: and what have you tried so far?

Comment: i am still searching but not yet find anything .

Answer (score 4):

You can get the current wifi name(SSID) like this:

```
string SSID;
var icp = Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();
if (icp != null)
{
    if (icp.WlanConnectionProfileDetails != null)
    {
        SSID = icp.WlanConnectionProfileDetails.GetConnectedSsid();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't get WiFi's name AFAIK , here are all the informations you can get using NetworkInformation class.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202859%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Comment: but it is not providing the name of wifi we are using